# Should I use a cite attribute, at its current state?

Tags: html, attributes

So, the `cite`attribute is used with an URL as a value to indicate the source of a quote (for `<q>` and `<blockquote>`) or a page that can provide additional information (for `<del>` and `<ins>`).

Because this URL isn't shown in any way to the end user by the browser, the only reason to put it in the document would be for non-user, hence crawlers, bots and whatever. You could also use it with a script, but that's not in my intentions.

My question: is it, from your experience, worth it to bother with this attribute or should I pass over?
What if I linked to that URL with `a`, which is way more common: would your answer change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `cite`, the semantic web can be ours today. Cite becomes more important the more people use it. If everyone used the attribute, developers could make some pretty awesome stuff.

Using extra semantics such as these are also good for SEO. Even if Google does not currently look for it, it is a safe bet they eventually will.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional attribute which you can use if you feel it has value in your case. If you are concerned that your quote's legitimacy might be in question, and you have a source you took it from, then adding the `cite` attribute gives inquisitive people or bots an idea of where you got the information. If you don't really care that people know where you got the quote from, then don't bother.

You might also put it for your own reference so when you look at it a year from now you'll have that information at hand.